# Wreath product, semi-direct product, and partitions

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product, wreath-product

Any help with the question which follows will be greatly appreciated.  I'm working through Dixon and Mortimer's *Permutation Groups* and have a question regarding a particular semi-direct product related to wreath products.  First I'll give a (slightly expanded) account of what Dixon and Mortimer say, and then my attempt to untangle their claims.

Let $\Omega$ be a set and $\Sigma$ a partition of $\Omega$ into equally sized subsets.  We define the automorphism group of $\Sigma$ to be 
$$
  G:=\mathrm{Aut}(\Sigma) := \{x \in \mathrm{Sym}(\Omega) : \forall \Delta \subseteq \Omega,\  \Delta^x \in \Sigma \iff \Delta \in \Sigma\}
$$
where the notation $\Delta^x = \{\alpha^x : \alpha \in \Delta\}$ (recalling that $\mathrm{Sym}(\Omega)$ acts on $\Omega$).  Then $G$ has a natural action on $\Sigma$ given by $\Delta \mapsto \Delta^x$ for every $x \in G$ and every $\Delta \in \Sigma$.  Let $B$ denote the kernel of this action:
$$
  B = \{x \in G : \Delta^x = \Delta, \ \forall \Delta \in \Sigma\}
$$
Begin with the observation that we have an isomorphism
$$
  B \cong \prod_{\Delta \in \Sigma} \mathrm{Sym}(\Delta)
$$
given by the map $x \mapsto (x|_{\Delta})_{\Delta \in \Sigma}$ (each $x \in \mathrm{Sym}(\Omega)$ and fixes each $\Delta \in \Sigma$, thus restricts to a permutation on each such $\Delta$).

Next Dixon and Mortimer observe that $\mathrm{Sym}(\Sigma)$ acts on $B$ "by permuting the components of the elements of $B$ in a natural way."  Given this action, it makes sense to consider the semi-direct product
$$
  B \rtimes \mathrm{Sym}(\Sigma)
$$
and the authors claim: "it's easy to see that"
$$
  G \cong B \rtimes \mathrm{Sym}(\Sigma).
$$

---

So here's my attempt at unpacking a bit of what they claim.  Before we try to write-down the action of $\mathrm{Sym}(\Sigma)$ on $B$, we fix some notation.  Every $\Delta \in \Sigma$ has the same cardinality, so we can choose for each pair $\Delta, \Delta^\prime \in \Sigma$ a particular bijection
$$
  \phi_{\Delta}^{\Delta^\prime} : \Delta \to \Delta^\prime
$$
with the properties that 
$$
  \phi_{\Delta^\prime}^{\Delta} = (\phi_{\Delta}^{\Delta^\prime})^{-1}
$$
and 
$$
  \phi_{\Delta^\prime}^{\Delta^{\prime \prime}} \circ \phi_{\Delta}^{\Delta^\prime}  = \phi_{\Delta}^{\Delta^{\prime \prime}}
$$
for every $\Delta, \Delta^\prime , \Delta^{\prime \prime} \in \Sigma$ (composition is left to right, so in the above composite $\phi_{\Delta^\prime}^{\Delta^{\prime \prime}}$ is first).

Now, for the action of $\mathrm{Sym}(\Sigma)$ on $B$, represent an element of $B$ by its image 
$$
  (x_\Delta)_{\Delta \in \Sigma} \in \prod_{\Delta \in \Sigma} \mathrm{Sym}(\Delta).
$$
Then given $\sigma \in \mathrm{Sym}(\Sigma)$, we define
$$
  (x_\Delta)_{\Delta \in \Sigma} ^{\sigma} := (x_{(\Delta)\sigma}^\Delta)_{\Delta\in \Sigma}
$$
where 
$$
  x_{(\Delta)\sigma}^{\Delta} = \phi_{\Delta}^{(\Delta)\sigma} \circ x_{(\Delta)\sigma} \circ \phi_{(\Delta)\sigma}^{\Delta} \in \mathrm{Sym}(\Delta)
$$
Note that we apply elements in Symmetric groups on the right so that the image of $\Delta \in \Sigma$ under the permutation $\sigma \in \mathrm{Sym}(\Sigma)$ is denoted $(\Delta)\sigma$.

**Question 1.**  Does this seem like the correct action?

Now we want to actually prove that there's an isomorphism $B \rtimes \mathrm{Sym} (\Sigma)\cong G$, so I began by trying to write down a map $\Psi : B \rtimes \mathrm{Sym} (\Sigma) \to G$ as follows: send

$$
  ((x_\Delta)_{\Delta\in  \Sigma} , \  \sigma) \in B \rtimes \mathrm{Sym} (\Sigma)
$$
to the map $x : \Omega \to \Omega$ defined by 
$$
  x : \alpha \mapsto (\alpha)x_{(\Delta)\sigma}^{\Delta}
$$
where $\alpha \in \Delta$.

Thus far I've been able to prove that $\Psi$ is a well defined set map (by which I mean that the image actually lands in $G$).  I've been struggling proving the homomorphism property however.

**Question 2.**  Does this seem like the correct way to define the homomorphism (eventual isomorphism) from $B \rtimes \mathrm{Sym} (\Sigma) \to G$?  If it's not, do you know the correct map to define?  If it is, do you know how to prove it's a homomorphism?

**Question 3.** Any obvious ways to clean up this unruly notation?

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: I am afraid I don't have time to help much with this and I am finding it takes too long to do battle with your notation. I think the answer to Question 1 is not quite! You need to replace $(\Delta)\sigma$ by $(\Delta)\sigma^{-1}$ in your definition of the action. As for Question 2, it looks to me as though everything in the image of your proposed action lies in what should be the image of $B$ (the kernel of the action on the blocks) which cannot be right.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to note. You said that the bloc of $\Sigma$ are all of the same size. And $B=\prod_{\Delta\in \Sigma}Sym(\Delta)$, then $$B\simeq Sym(|\Delta|)^{|\Sigma|}$$ for some $\Delta \in \Sigma$.

Then $$G\simeq Sym(|\Delta|)^{|\Sigma|}\rtimes Sym(\Sigma)=Sym(\Delta)\wr Sym(\Sigma)$$.